# Opamp with Caps

Tags: operational-amplifier, waveform

I am having an issue with the output of an opamp. Not sure its the opamp but also not sure what this circuit is doing.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3xYfU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I should be getting something like 
[image: wave]

but i dont get this . Any idea on what to check or why .  Would it be the caps? or the opamp?

thanks

Comment: If somebody said to you "normally I'm healthy but one day I wasn't - what could be wrong with me", what would be the first question you would ask?

Comment: did you see a doctor?

Comment: With no input and no feedback it could be doing almost anything

Comment: He's trying to make a comparator it seems, no feedback needed then. You should not connect capacitors like that to the output. Why would you do that ? Just "making something" and hoping it works is a recipe for disaster and you learn nothing.

Comment: @user41758 what do you want this circuit to do?

Comment: this is not the whole circuit , its only part of the circuit in a board. as the whole circuit board drawing is huge, i posted the part that i am testing and having issues. the input is actually starting at 20volts and goes threw 3 other circuits just like this . with the output feeding into then next op-amp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They clearly seem they are there as low pass filters. You also have to notice that since this is an open loop amplifier there will be a very huge gain.

So unless the input signal is very small the output will be saturated.

Comment: That helps alot. And makes sense cause I will sometimes notice the wave form show then disrepair after a few mins.. So somewhere i am getting too much voltage in the input. Both the pos and neg are comming from other op-amps.. but if i still cant solve this i may just draw out the whole circuit and see what people think.. Thanks

Comment: Being honestly it seems also a bit strange to me.

Comment: Just looked at the data sheet here http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tl081.pdf and the large! signal amplification is typical at 200V per mV ... do you see anything wrong with this HUGE gain?  (I could not find the exact match but I bet it's similar or larger...)